# Ebean Expression icontains List of elements

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a query like this:

```
find.where()
            .or(Expr.or(Expr.like("isbn", query),
                    Expr.icontains("book.tags", query)),
                    Expr.or(Expr.icontains("book.authors", query),
                            Expr.icontains("book.title", query)))
            .findList();
```

The find Object is just a regulular Finder in play2 Java, nothing magical.

Now as you can see this Edition object holds a reference to book which has a List of tags.

This doesn't compile because it's confused of the tags because it cannot query a list, how to query a list of stuff in ebean expressions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally nailed this beast using ebeans documentation on their website and ALOT of trial and error:

```
return find.where()
            .or(Expr.or(Expr.like("isbn", query),
            Expr.icontains("book.tags.name", query)),
                Expr.or(Expr.icontains("book.authors.name", query),
                        Expr.icontains("book.title", query))).findList();
```

The key is reaching all the way in on icontains.